# Given a list of tuples representing ranges ,condense the ranges (Write a function)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am learning Python 2.x and would like to address following issue.
Need a function to condense the ranges

Problem :Given a list of tuples representing ranges ,condense the ranges

```
Input : [(2,3),(4,5),(7,8),(8,10),(12,15)]
Output :[(2,5),(7,10),(12,15)]
```

Any pointer or help would be great help

Comment: "I am learning Python 2.x"   For real, just learn 3.x. Python 2 will be phased out.

Comment: Why are `(2, 3)` and `(4, 5)` joined together into `(2, 5)`? ranges in python usually do not include the last element of the range.

Comment: Paste what you've done so far. We are happy to help but we will not do your homework for you.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque (2,3) and (4,5) joined together into (2,5) as they are in same range.We need to condense the the ranges

Comment: @gonczor sorry for the trouble however I am a newbie to Python and got totally confused.Initially I thought of using for loop to iterate over tuples and compare them ( but somehow not getting a right way of doing it

Comment: Just paste it and we will think

Answer (score 0):

You could proceed for example as in the example below. The idea is to process individual intervals `(lb, ub)` and for each lower bound `lb`, mark an increase by 1, while for each upper bound `ub`, mark a decrease by `-1`.
Assuming integer input, the code effectively considers intervals `(lb-0.5,ub+0.5)` so that for example `(2, 3)` and `(4, 5)` are merged. In order to avoid using floating point numbers as dictionary keys, the dictionary `stat` stores double the number...

When you then process these individual "break" points, the total accumulated value (`cnt`) tells you how many intervals cover current point. As long as this number is greater than zero, we are inside a merged segment. If it drops to zero, we can take the next breakpoint and repeat the procedure...

```
spec = {}
L = [(2,3),(4,12),(7,8),(8,10),(12,15)]
for lb, ub in L:
    lb, ub = min(lb, ub), max(lb, ub)
    for v in [2*lb - 1, 2*ub + 1]:
        if not v in spec: spec[v] = 0
    spec[2*lb - 1] += 1
    spec[2*ub + 1] -= 1

break_points = sorted(spec.keys())
N = len(break_points)

idx = -1
while idx < N-1:
    idx += 1

    lb, ub = break_points[idx], None
    cnt = spec[lb]

    while cnt > 0:
        idx += 1
        ub = break_points[idx]
        cnt += spec[ub]

    print((lb+1)/2, (ub-1)/2)
    #prints (2, 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Merging ranges is not as easy and straightforward as it seems. You have to pay attention to overlaps over multiple input ranges, as well as inclusions, i/e ranges entirely contained in another.

It is also necessary to ensure that the input is sorted by start values.

Here is a somewhat tested solution:

```
def overlap(r1, r2):
    return r1[1] >= r2[0] - 1    # <-- -1 to ensure ranges like (2, 3) and (4, 5) merge into (2, 5)

def merge_range(r1, r2):
    s1, e1 = r1
    s2, e2 = r2
    return (min(s1, s2), max(e1, e2))

def regroup_ranges(rgs):
    assert all([s <= e for s, e in rgs])
    if len(rgs) == 0:
        return rgs

    rngs.sort()

    regrouped = [rgs[0]]

    for r2 in rgs[1:]:
        r1 = regrouped.pop()
        if overlap(r1, r2):
            regrouped.append(merge_range(r1, r2))
        else:
            regrouped.append(r1)
            regrouped.append(r2)

    return regrouped
```

#### Tests:

```
def test_regroup_ranges():
    rngs = [(2, 3), (4, 5), (7, 8), (8, 10), (12, 15)]
    compressed = [(2, 5), (7, 10), (12, 15)]
    print(regroup_ranges(rngs))
    assert regroup_ranges(rngs) == compressed

    rngs = [(2, 8), (4, 5), (7, 8), (8, 10), (12, 15)]
    compressed = [(2, 10), (12, 15)]
    print(regroup_ranges(rngs))
    assert regroup_ranges(rngs) == compressed

    rngs = [(2, 3) ,(4, 5), (1, 16), (8, 10), (12, 15)]
    compressed = [(1, 16)]
    print(regroup_ranges(rngs))
    assert regroup_ranges(rngs) == compressed

    rngs = [(2, 3), (4, 20), (7, 8), (8, 10), (12, 15)]
    compressed = [(2, 20)]
    print(regroup_ranges(rngs))
    assert regroup_ranges(rngs) == compressed

    rngs = [(2, 3), (5, 8), (10, 12)]
    compressed = [(2, 3), (5, 8), (10, 12)]
    print(regroup_ranges(rngs))
    assert regroup_ranges(rngs) == compressed

    rngs = [(2, 3)]
    compressed = [(2, 3)]
    print(regroup_ranges(rngs))
    assert regroup_ranges(rngs) == compressed

    rngs = []
    compressed = []
    print(regroup_ranges(rngs))
    assert regroup_ranges(rngs) == compressed

    print("***all tests pass***")

test_regroup_ranges()
```

#### Tests results:

```
[(2, 5), (7, 10), (12, 15)]
[(2, 10), (12, 15)]
[(1, 16)]
[(2, 20)]
[(2, 3), (5, 8), (10, 12)]
[(2, 3)]
[]
***all tests pass***
```